# Multiple OpenGL ES 2 Android Renders

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to have multiple renders displaying at one time on a screen?  Like split an android screen into 4 quadrants and on each quadrant display a cube?  I see it possible for OpenGL but that's GLUT and is windows based.  I am looking into how to do it for android but i haven't come across anything describing that yet.  Here's my main activity that creates the render.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private MyGLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity

        // "this" is the reference to activity
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        // The following call pauses the rendering thread.
        // If your OpenGL application is memory intensive,
        // you should consider de-allocating objects that
        // consume significant memory here.
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        // The following call resumes a paused rendering thread.
        // If you de-allocated graphic objects for onPause()
        // this is a good place to re-allocate them.
        mGLView.onResume();
    }
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView
{

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;
    Context context;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;
        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        Log.d("Test", "GL initialized");
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't do this with a single GLSurfaceView. You can divide the screen into four quadrants by calling glViewport to map the scene onto that quadrant. You can then call your draw functions and then repeat for each subsequent quadrant.

Example:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
< render first quadrant >

glViewport(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height / 2);
< render second quadrant >
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

GLSurfaceView is not designed to do this, but you can do it by using TextureViews instead.  Look at the online documentation for TextureView.  The simplest way to do it is to create a single thread that renders each of the TextureViews in turn.  If you want more than one OpenGL ES context running concurrently, that is much more complicated, but it has been discussed recently on the Khronos.org OpenGL ES forum.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking to run them concurrently.  Basically 4 renders running at the same time, each on a quadrant of the screen.

Comment: Ive tried this approach but sometimes there is corruption and texture views seem to get other texture views texture instead of what was actually drawn. I don't think TextureView supports more than one instance reliably.

Comment: It has been a couple of years since I worked with TextureView, but I see that Google FINALLY published some information about how it really works here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html